# OSX 10.7 - Hide DS_Store Files but not htaccess files in finder

Tags: osx-lion

I'm working on OSX 10.7 Lion, and i have finder showing me all the hidden files, so i can get at my .htaccess files.

I'm wondering if there is a way to just hide the .DS_Store files in finder, so they don't show up everywhere, while still being able to see my .htaccess files in the finder.

Anyone know if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, show/hiding "hidden" files (those that start with a leading dot) is an all-or-nothing boolean in Finder.app's settings.  Wish there was a way to hide *just* the .DS_Store file, too ...

Comment: as @dossy said, it's an "all or nothing" thing, but you can always get it via apps like FTP clients (that show all files), or via the terminal (`ls -a`). You can even open it like this: `open -e .htaccess`

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed they are visible in Transmit, but it's a bit of a pain to have to open transmit if i just want to grab a copy of any .htaccess file from a folder, and i don't want to see all those .DS_Store files floating around everyone... especially on my desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create symbolic links from .htaccess to htaccess in each directory so you will have a reference to the hidden file you can access from within Finder(or other applications).

To do this just go into the directory in question in Terminal (`cd /Path/to/directory`) and link the files (`ln -s .htaccess htaccess`). The -s makes it a symbolic link, which means it references the original linked file instead of creating a second file. When you edit htaccess you will actually be editing .htaccess

Hope this helps, you can read `man ln` for more information on linking files.

Another solution would be a software add-on to Finder that allows you to filter files out from the listing. I don't know of any that do this, but it is what you would want to look for.

Comment: This is as close a solution as i've heard yet. Thanks for the tip! I've actually found a few other decent uses for this functionality too!